# eror 404 in react-routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a problem. Look at my code:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        url: '/' +this.props.lang+ '/panel',
        about: '',
        user: '',
        userPath: ''
    }


}

componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({
        about: this.state.url + '/about',
        user: this.state.url + '/user/1',
        userPath: this.state.url + '/user/:id',

    })
}

//View
                <div>
                    <Route exact path={this.state.url} component={Home} />
                    <Route path={this.state.about} component={About} />
                    <Route path={this.state.userPath} component={User} />
                </div>
```

The most of links works correctly excect one - users. If i click on link "user", component will be render. But if I refresh my website, I'll have error 404. Any other link works correctly.
Of course I can open /user (without var but this page is empty). Error 404 is if I try open /user/1. Why? I use React component in Laravel project.

Comment: Is it happening in dev server ?

Comment: Yes. I use React component in Laravel project.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are setting the path inside your `componentDidMount` function, and therefore, when the page loads, all of the URL's are `''`.

I don't think you can do like this, you probably have to set the urls in your constructor.

Like this:

```
const baseUrl = '/' +this.props.lang+ '/panel';

this.state = {
  url: baseUrl,
  about: baseUrl + '/about',
  user: baseUrl + '/user/1',
  userPath: baseUrl + '/user/:id'
}
```

Comment: Any other url was load correctly except this one. But I try youre code I still have this same problem. Propably problem is in var. I can open /user (of course component is empty but I don't have error 404) but if I go to /url/1, it'll display 404 error.

Comment: You have to go to /en/panel/user/1 to view the /user/1 url

Comment: I go to localhost:8000/pl/panel/user/1 (it's full url). Like I wrote, It's Laravel project with react component.